# Why is suggested code is better in for loop to generate dynamic HTML code to display list of works to evaluate?

Tags: javascript, performance, array

The point was that we have a series of dynamic data that comes from the server and must be added to the view, and the other thing is that given the property of the objects that are true and false, add a series of classes to it.
For example, I created an array myself, so that you know an understanding of the data structure that the server will come up with

Below is my first code:

```
   var works = [{
            workTitle: "WW II military operations",
            answered: true
        },
        {
            workTitle: "Female scientist",
            answered: false
        },
        {
            workTitle: "Animals (like Apple who have used Jaguar, Leopard, Panther etc for OS X versions)",
            answered: false
        },
        {
            workTitle: "Myths and legends, like American rockets",
            answered: true
        },
        {
            workTitle: "iot.js",
            answered: true
        },
        {
            workTitle: "Random code name generators",
            answered: true
        },
        {
            workTitle: "Dinosaur names",
            answered: false
        },
        {
            workTitle: "Myths and legends, like American rockets Animals (like Apple who have used Jaguar, Leopard, Panther etc for OS X versions)",
            answered: true
        },
        {
            workTitle: "Try your hand at creating your next project (or product) name with this cool name generator! Project Jive-theory is just around the",
            answered: true
        },
    ];

    //create section tag and add class to that 
    let mainElement = document.getElementById("main");
    let containerWorks = document.createElement('section');
    containerWorks.classList.add("works-container")

    //generate HTML code by dynamic values
    let len = works.length - 1;
    let i = len;
    for (; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (works[i].answered) {
            containerWorks.innerHTML += `<div class="not-allowed work-box d-flex justify-content-center      align-items-center p-3"
            ui-sref="App.Managment.UsersManagment.UserList">
            <div class="title">
                ${works[i].workTitle}
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-lock text-white fa-2x lock-icon"></i>
            <div class="not-answer-box font-weight-bold">Previously Evaluated</div>
            </div>`;


        } else {
            containerWorks.innerHTML += `<div class="pointer work-box d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center p-3"
            ui-sref="App.Managment.UsersManagment.UserList">
            <div class="title">
            ${works[i].workTitle}
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-reply text-white fa-2x enter-icon"></i>
            <div class="answer-box font-weight-bold">Click To Evaluate</div>
            </div>`;
        }
    }
    mainElement.appendChild(containerWorks);
```

But this is suggested code for me by others and we have written this code:

```
...    

//generate HTML code by dynamic values
let len = works.length - 1;
let i = len;

let condition = {
    'false': {
        iClass: `fa-reply enter-icon`,
        divClass: `pointer`,
        textContent: 'Click To Evaluate'
    },
    'true': {
        iClass: `fa-lock lock-icon`,
        divClass: `not-allowed`,
        textContent: "Previously Evaluated"
    }
}

for (; i >= 0; i--) {

    let cond = condition[works[i].answered];

    containerWorks.innerHTML += `<div class="` + cond.divClass + ` work-box d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center p-3"
        ui-sref="App.Managment.UsersManagment.UserList">
        <div class="title">
        ${works[i].workTitle}
        </div>
        <i class="fas ` + cond.iClass + ` text-white fa-2x"></i>
        <div class="answer-box font-weight-bold">` + cond.textContent + `</div>
        </div>`;
}
mainElement.appendChild(containerWorks);
```

I think the suggested code is better in some ways, but I am not sure! and why?
If it's really better can someone tell me why?
And also is there any better way to write that part of the code?

Comment: @downvoters care to comment!

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you must be author of the code you post and you write yourself, that the second variant isn't yours.

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RoToRa no, the second one is  suggested to me and we have written in my code, but i don't know which one better and  i don't know is there other way.
both of them are my code, but the second one is suggested code

Comment: @BCdotWEB I edited the question bro.

Comment: "_Why is suggested code is better in for loop to generate dynamic HTML code?_" does not sounds like a decent description of **the task accomplished by the code**. Perhaps something like "_Display list of works to evaluate_" would be fitting...

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ edited bro

Comment: The "authorship rule" does not literally require code typed or dreamt up by the user asking. They should be a maintainer, if not author, and in a position to put the code under *creative commons* by presenting it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested code might be considered better because it has less duplicate code. In this case most of the HTML strings are duplicated in your first example. Code with less duplication is less work and less error prone to change. For example, if the classes for the outer div needed to be changed, then in your example you would have to change two places instead of one, and you might forget to change one of the two places, causing a bug.

For a case like this, where there are only two cases, and the two pieces of code are nearby the benefits are smaller than if there were more cases than true or false. Say there was a partially-completed state that needed to be added. Whether it makes sense to reduce duplication in this particular case is a matter of opinion, I would argue, since it does make the code a little more complicated. It might be fine or even better to just wait until the next time the requirements change, since then you will know more about how the code should be at that point. If there were 10 different cases, then the duplication and therefore the chances of making a mistake go up, so it would be clearer what the right choice is.